# Read an MVC @Html.TextBoxFor from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I must read, on a change event, the value of a `html.TextBoxFor` field.

Now I have this element in my MVC Form:

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pod, new {
     @class = "inputStyle180", @title = "Pod", @onchange = "onChangePod();"
})
}
```

And this Javascript function:

```
 function onChangePod() {
    var Trovato = false;
    //var sPod = document.getElementById("Pod").value;
    var Pod = $('#Pod').val();
    alert(sPod);
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("VerificaDatiUtenza", "EELAutoletture")', {
      Pod: Pod
    }, function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        Trovato = true;
        if (i == "Denominazione") {
          $('#Denominazione').val(item);
        }
        if (i == "Localita") {
          $('#Localita').val(item);
        }
      });
    });
    if (Trovato == false) {
      alert("ATTENZIONE! Pod non in anagrafica");
    }
  };
```

But the variable `Pod` is empty

Comment: `var Pod = $('#Pod').val();` works fine (unless you have multiple elements with `id=`"Pod"`)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke if `Pod` is a nested property of complex model than id will include a prefix so `$('#Pod').val()` won't work. I think using `$("#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.Pod)").val()` would be better in this case

Comment: @AlexArt., NO! If it was a nested property then `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pod, .)` would throw an exception - it would need to be `@Html.TextBOxForm( m => m.SomePropery.Pod, ...)`. OP's code works perfectly unless there are other elements with `id="Pod"` - it which case it will only find the first one

Comment: @Stephen Muecke NO! for example you have Model->NestedModel->Pod and you are using Editor template for NestedModel then the id will be NestedModel_Pod

Comment: Anyway `$("#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.Pod)").val()` will generate a correct Id for both cases

Comment: Will you please add the actual html generated by your use of `@Html.TextBoxFor()` so that other users stop wasting their time trying to add answers to this question

Answer (score 0):

You can send the value to the function as input:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pod, new { @class = "inputStyle180", @title = "Pod", @onchange = "onChangePod(this.value);" })}
```

and

```
function onChangePod(Pod) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.. creating id in @Html.TextBoxFor..

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pod, new { @id="Pod",@class = "inputStyle180", @title = "Pod", @onchange = "onChangePod();" })}
```

Here is your function method

```
function onChangePod() {
var Trovato = false;
var Pod = $('#Pod').val();
alert(Pod );
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("VerificaDatiUtenza", "EELAutoletture")', { Pod: Pod }, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        Trovato = true;
        if (i == "Denominazione") {
            $('#Denominazione').val(item);
        }
        if (i == "Localita") {
            $('#Localita').val(item);
        }
    });
});
if (Trovato == false) {
    alert("ATTENZIONE! Pod non in anagrafica");
}
};
```

Comment: OP's `TextBoxFor()` usage already adds `id="Pod"` - doing so again is pointless.

Comment: which one you are mentioning as id ..you mean this as id **m => m.Pod**

Comment: Yes, `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pod, ...)` generates `<input type="text" id="Pod" name="Pod" .... />`

Comment: yeah i got it.. but sometimes the jquery is not recognizing this id .. i solved this by creating @id="idName" and tried getting the value of a textbox ,It worked out .. thats y i mentioned this..

Comment: _but sometimes the jquery is not recognizing this id_?  If its not working for you then you have made a mistake in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already using inline script you can use `Html.IdFor` helper to get an id  that is generated for `Pod` property
so yo can use something like

```
function onChangePod() {
   var Trovato = false;
   var Pod = $("#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.Pod)").val();
   alert(Pod );
   $.getJSON('@Url.Action("VerificaDatiUtenza", "EELAutoletture")', { Pod: Pod }, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        Trovato = true;
        if (i == "Denominazione") {
            $('#Denominazione').val(item);
        }
        if (i == "Localita") {
            $('#Localita').val(item);
        }
    });
   });
   if (Trovato == false) {
    alert("ATTENZIONE! Pod non in anagrafica");
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use name attribute to get the `Pod` input.

```
var Pod = $('input[name="Pod"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get item by Id in javascript, you must set Id for that. (`$("#Pod").Val()`).
Anyway you have 2 options.

1) you can get item by name ex: `$("input[name="Pod"]).Val()`)

2) change you View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pod, new {@class = "inputStyle180", @title = "Pod", 
@onchange = "onChangePod();", @id="Pod"})
```

then use

`$("#Pod").Val()`

Comment: Please add some explanation. Currently, your answer is flagged "low quality" and might get removed.